# Which context should i use in a service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-context, android-service-binding

I have two services in my application - `lA_svc` & `lB_svc`.

The `MainActivity` lauches `lA_svc` - which `context` should I use for launching the service from the activity?

Now `lA_svc` sends an intent to launch `lB_svc` - which `context` should I use here in the `startService()` method?

After a while, `lB_svc` sends an `intent` to launch `lA_svc`, which `context` do I use here?

Can you please link any gist(s), example(s) to understand the context as per which the services are to be launched?

Comment: `android.app.Service` extends `android.content.ContextWrapper` so use that `ContextWrapper`

Comment: @pskink Can you provide an example? I do know that. But I am starting a service, from a service, which context should I use while sending an intent from the service?

Comment: example of what? you simply use `this` inside your `Service` as a `Context`

Comment: `Activity` and `Service` both are `Context` so use:

    `this`

Comment: This results in an error

Comment: what error? whats the stacktrace?

Comment: Okay if its an error then I suspect you are calling inside an inner class change `this` to `YourActivityName.this` or `YourServiceName.this`

Comment: i dont see any `startService` related error

Comment: @pskink Then what is the error exactly?

Comment: how can i know your errors? what does *NOT* work in your code actually?

Comment: @pksink Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726533/why-is-the-timer-firing-intents-randomly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which context should I use for launching the service from the
>   activity?

A `Service` can be started from every component. Since you are in an Activity I assume that you have access to two `Context`:

- Activity context
- Application context

It doesn't matter which one you use, but it makes more sense to me, to use the one of your enclosing component, so the `Activity` context (use `this`).

> Now lA_svc sends an intent to launch lB_svc. - which context should I
>   use here in the startService() method?

Again, you are allowed to start a service from every components, and again it makes sense to use the `Context` of your enclosing component, so `Service` context (just use `this` in your service).

> After a while, lB_svc sends an intent to launch lA_svc, which context
>   do I use here?

The problem here is the same: you want to start a `Service` from another `Service`. So just use your `Service` context.

The best article I have ever read about Context is [this](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) from Dave Smith.

Answer (score 0):

Basically both your Activity and Services are all context. While starting a service, it doesn't matter which context you use. Use you Activity/Service or even application context.

[Here's](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) a nice article that specifies when actually it matters which context to use.